# Defold set animation and cursor in a single run

Tags: lua, defold

Lets assume I have some input function which decides which direction to run. The atlas file being referenced to the game object has 8 (isometric) walk animations (same frame count, one animation per 1/8 rotation). Thus, if the rotation changes I want to set another animation but with its cursor at the same time (For the user the object should only rotate without starting the animation again)

I tried to do the following in the `on_input` function

```lua
self.cursor = go.get("#sprite", "cursor")
msg.post('#sprite','play_animation',{id = hash('run_5')})
go.set("#sprite", "cursor", cursor)
```

which is obviously not working because `msg.post` is async thus line 3 runs after 2 is being executed. How to get this done properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can find some solutions here: at [defold-forum](https://forum.defold.com/t/animation-during-the-jump-animation-it-plays-walking-animation-if-pressed-right-or-left/43008).I can't write comments, so I had to write here.